# Translation of "I didn't know that"

Tags: traduction, temps-grammatical

> Paul is coming to the party tonight? I didn't know that!

What is the appropriate translation for "I didn't know that!" here?

> Paul va venir à la fête ce soir ? Je ne le savais pas !

In particular, should the *imparfait* or the *passé composé* ("*Je ne l'ai pas su !*") be used? On the one hand, the knowledge is a state and not just one event, so we should use the *imparfait*. But the *passé composé* is quite often used for negative sentences similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Je ne savais pas!" or "Je ne le savais pas!". You could also use "Je n'étais pas au courant!"